# Problem merging two rasters in Qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

I have two rasters in Geotiff, same CRS. I tried to merge them and I have this error code

```
ERROR 4: `C:/Anita_Tepoztln/Rasters/e142.tif' does not exist in the file system, 
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name. 

ERROR 4: `C:/Anita_Tepoztln/Rasters/e145.tif' does not exist in the file system, 
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 509, in 
sys.exit(main()) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 392, in main 
ulx = file_infos[0].ulx 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong.

I am able to load the rasters and see them, not merging them

I am using Qgis Lisboa standallone installation, on  Win7 64 16gb of RAM

Comment: The two DEMs are in the same CRS, but do they match the project's CRS as well?  If not, that's probably the issue.

Comment: Yes, raster layers and the project are in the same crs (EPSG 4326, lat lon wgs84), so this is not the issue

Comment: Are the two files really geotiffs with CRS information inside? What do you get from gdalinfo <filename>?

Comment: yes, I can see all the information about each raster layer, Do you want a copy of them?

Comment: For Instance: Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: C:\Anita_Tepoztlán\Rasters\e145.tif
       C:\Anita_Tepoztlán\Rasters\e145.tif.aux.xml
Size is 7200, 3600
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]] etc.....

Comment: Yes, looks good. But the á in the folder path may spoil it. At least it does so here, with the non-ASCII-Letters omitted in the error log. Can you try a folder with only ASCII-letters?

Comment: You are right Andre!As soon as I changed the á in folder name all worked like a charm, it took Qgis a few seeconds to merge the raster layers. I hope this answer help others. Thanks for the advise

Comment: @NWT Adam's advice does work,I change the folder's name and my QGIS perfectly do the Raster Merge work. Thanks, bro~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is "Anita_Tepoztlán" your Windows User name?

Non-ASCII-characters can cause breakdowns.

You may also need to reinstall QGIS is in a folder with only ASCII-characters in the title as well.

Comment: No, it was the name of the folder where I have all the raster layers

Comment: In fact I had the same problem and the problem was that the path to the images contained one "á" so I changed to "a" and the algorith run normally.